# iOS SVG lag when free-hand drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, performance, svg

I'm writing a simple drawing "thing" for our users. It uses SVG. All of the users have iPads, either 4s or Air 2s. I'm testing on a 2 (2nd gen, *not* Air 2). All iPads are running iOS 9.2 and using Safari.

When free-hand drawing on the SVG element, there is substantial lag. On the 2nd gen it's "almost tolerable", on the 4s it's "incredibly painful". Not sure about the Air 2s, but if it's scaling the way the 4s did, I'd say it's "kill me now". Interesting how the better hardware lags more, but I suppose it could have something to do with the increased resolution, but still...

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance? The lag is also noticible when drawing ready shapes (rectangle, line (path), and ellipse), but it's something we can live with.

Here's the code I'm using to bind the event handlers (using jQuery) for the free-hand drawing.

```
Floor.bindFreeHand = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sPB, d, p1, segments;
    Floor._jElement.off(EventTypes.pointerDown + " " + EventTypes.pointerUp).on(EventTypes.pointerDown, function (e) {
        var pI1 = PointerInfo.parse(e);
        sPB = new SvgPathsBuilder();
        d = sPB.moveTo(pI1.x, pI1.y).d();
        p1 = Svg.path(d).attr({
            "fill": "none",
            "stroke": Floor._color,
            "stroke-linecap": "round",
            "stroke-linejoin": "round",
            "stroke-opacity": Floor._opacity,
            "stroke-width": Floor._width
        });
        segments = p1.element.pathSegList;
        Floor._sElement.add(p1);
        Floor._jElement.on(EventTypes.pointerMove, function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            segments.appendItem(p1.element.createSVGPathSegLinetoAbs(e.offsetX, e.offsetY));
            //var pI2 = PointerInfo.parse(e);
            //d = sPB.lineTo(pI2.x, pI2.y).d();
            //p1.attr("d", d);
        });
    }).on(EventTypes.pointerUp, function (e) {
        Floor._jElement.off(EventTypes.pointerMove);
    });
};
```

And here's the `PointerInfo` and `EventTypes` objects:

```
var PointerInfo = (function () {
    function PointerInfo(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    PointerInfo.parse = function (e) {
        var x = e.offsetX - 2, y = e.offsetY - 1;
        return new PointerInfo(x, y);
    };
    return PointerInfo;
})();

var EventTypes = (function () {
    function EventTypes() {
    }
    EventTypes.touch = EventTypes.touch || ("ontouchstart" in window);
    EventTypes.pointerDown = EventTypes.touch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown";
    EventTypes.pointerMove = EventTypes.touch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove";
    EventTypes.pointerUp = EventTypes.touch ? "touchend" : "mouseup";
    EventTypes.pointerLeave = EventTypes.touch ? "touchleave" : "mouseout";
    return EventTypes;
})();
```

All of these are compiled down from TypeScript.

Comment: Use the SVG DOM to add pathSeg objects to the existing line rather than reconstructing the line every pointer move.

Comment: Ok, so I went down to the SVG DOM with `segments.appendItem(p1.element.createSVGPathSegLinetoAbs(e.offsetX, e.offsetY));`, but the performance is identical, still lags just as much as it did with the previous attempt.

Comment: Figured it out, look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, after spending two days on it and disabling everything else on the page and every other script being loaded. It turned out that it was CSS that was causing the lag. The SVG element that was being drawn on had a background pattern created via gradients to look like a grid. Apparently as path was being updated on touchmove the element's layout was invalidated and Safari was force redrawing it constantly.

So, the moral of the story is that the performance issues in iOS Safari aren't always due to JavaScript. Fancy CSS effects also contribute to it especially if the element they're on is being manipulated constantly.

**UPDATE**

With Chrome 48, you can no longer set the path's segments because that API was deprecated and removed. The solution now is to constantly update the `d` attribute as the pointer moves. From my testing, there's no noticeable performance penalty, even on older devices such as the iPad 2nd gen.